# Calculate the exact value of the following expression

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Calculate the exact value of$$P=\dfrac{(10^{4}+324)(22^{4}+324)(34^{4}+324)(46^{4}+324)(58^{4}+324)}{(4^{4}+324)(16^{4}+324)(28^{4}+324)(40^{4}+324)(52^{4}+324)}$$

Any hint, pls. greetings!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$a^4+18^2=(a^2+18)^2-2a^2\cdot18=(a^2+18)^2-(6a)^2=\cdots$$

Now, $a^2+6a+18=c^2-6c+18\iff(a+c)\{(a-c)+6\}=0$ which holds true if $a-c+6=0\iff a=c-6$ assuming $a+c=0$

$\implies 10^2+6(10)+18=(10-6)^2-6(10-6)+18$ and $10^2+6(10)+18=(10+6)^2-6(10+6)+18$ and so on.

More generally,

$$a^4+(2b^2)^2=(a^2+2b^2)^2-2a^2\cdot2b^2=(a^2+2a^2)^2-(2ab)^2=\cdots$$

Comment: Exist another factorization $x^{4}+324=(x^{2}+6x+18)(x^{2}-6x+18)=(x(x+6)+18)(x(x-6)+18)$. With this, all terms are canceled quickly

Comment: @pablocn_, That is also derived from $a^2+6a+18=c^2-6c+18,$ right?

Comment: Yeah, but you 've edited many times Lol, greetings @lab

Answer (score 2):

$$P=\dfrac{(10^{4}+324)(22^{4}+324)(34^{4}+324)(46^{4}+324)(58^{4}+324)}{(4^{4}+324)(16^{4}+324)(28^{4}+324)(40^{4}+324)(52^{4}+324)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$P=\dfrac{(10324)(234580)(1336660)(4477780)(11316820)}{(580)(65860)(614980)(2560324)(7311940)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$P=\dfrac{(2421803920)(1336660)(4477780)(11316820)}{(38198800)(614980)(2560324)(7311940)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$P=373$$

Answer (score -3):

Wolfy says 373
(CCCLXXIII in Roman numerals).

Comment: What is Wolfy??, you referred to beautiful Wolfram Alpha?? lol

Comment: Anyway, is correct!!! :D, but you You have to write what you did :c

Comment: I pasted the expression, and Wolfy evaluated it. That's all.